# getting a horizontal scroll bar even 100% width

Tags: html, css

I've searched a lot and tryied lot of things but i couldn't fixed the problem.

I am getting an horizontal scroll bar even all my elements have 100% width's and no padding.

Please help me to get rid of it, her is the [link](http://ganim.com.tr/KUM).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can find the reason of your error by yourself when I paste the part of your CSS code:

```
 #menu {
  margin-left: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
 }
```

my advice to correct the error would be to create another element inside #div (usually for menu the unordered list - ul - is used) and set margin to it

Comment: OH MY!! :( thank you so much, sometimes two eyes are not enough.